# Draw Arrow on Canvas with React-Konva

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, konvajs

I would like to create a canvas where the user can draw an Arrow by using his mouse.

What I'm trying to accomplish is exactly this: https://jsfiddle.net/w33e9fpa/

But I don't understand how to convert that to React code, and my implementation currently doesn't work. When I run this code it seems that an arrow is drawn on the top left of the canvas, but nothing happens if I click on it.

Here's my code:

```
class DrawArrow extends Component {

  state = {
    isDrawing: false,
    mode: "brush"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 300;
    canvas.height = 300;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    this.setState({ canvas, context });
  }


  handleMouseDown = () => {
    this.setState({ isDrawing: true });

    // TODO: improve
    const stage = this.arrow.parent.parent;
    this.lastPointerPosition = stage.getPointerPosition();

    this.setState({
      posX: this.lastPointerPosition.x,
      poxY: this.lastPointerPosition.y
    })

  }

  handleMouseUp = () => {
    this.setState({ isDrawing: false });
  };

  handleMouseMove = () => {
    if (this.state.drawing === true) {
      const stage = this.arrow.parent.parent;
      this.lastPointerPosition = stage.getPointerPosition();
      var pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
      var oldPoints = this.arrow.points();
      this.arrow.points([oldPoints[0], oldPoints[1], pos.x, pos.y])
      this.arrow.getLayer().draw();
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Arrow
        points= {[this.state.posX,this.state.posY, this.state.posX, this.state.posY]}
        pointerLength= {20}
        pointerWidth=  {20}
        fill= 'black'
        stroke= 'black'
        strokeWidth= {4}
        onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
        onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}
      />
    );
  }
}


class NewWhite extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Stage width={900} height={700}>
        <Layer>
          <DrawArrow />
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for you help !

Comment: alternatively you can use an svg solution such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-arrows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Stage, Layer, Arrow, Circle, Line } from "react-konva";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

class Drawable {
  constructor(startx, starty) {
    this.startx = startx;
    this.starty = starty;
  }
}

class ArrowDrawable extends Drawable {
  constructor(startx, starty) {
    super(startx, starty);
    this.x = startx;
    this.y = starty;
  }
  registerMovement(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  render() {
    const points = [this.startx, this.starty, this.x, this.y];
    return <Arrow points={points} fill="black" stroke="black" />;
  }
}

class CircleDrawable extends ArrowDrawable {
  constructor(startx, starty) {
    super(startx, starty);
    this.x = startx;
    this.y = starty;
  }
  render() {
    const dx = this.startx - this.x;
    const dy = this.starty - this.y;
    const radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return (
      <Circle radius={radius} x={this.startx} y={this.starty} stroke="black" />
    );
  }
}

class FreePathDrawable extends Drawable {
  constructor(startx, starty) {
    super(startx, starty);
    this.points = [startx, starty];
  }
  registerMovement(x, y) {
    this.points = [...this.points, x, y];
  }
  render() {
    return <Line points={this.points} fill="black" stroke="black" />;
  }
}

class SceneWithDrawables extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      drawables: [],
      newDrawable: [],
      newDrawableType: "FreePathDrawable"
    };
  }

  getNewDrawableBasedOnType = (x, y, type) => {
    const drawableClasses = {
      FreePathDrawable,
      ArrowDrawable,
      CircleDrawable
    };
    return new drawableClasses[type](x, y);
  };

  handleMouseDown = e => {
    const { newDrawable } = this.state;
    if (newDrawable.length === 0) {
      const { x, y } = e.target.getStage().getPointerPosition();
      const newDrawable = this.getNewDrawableBasedOnType(
        x,
        y,
        this.state.newDrawableType
      );
      this.setState({
        newDrawable: [newDrawable]
      });
    }
  };

  handleMouseUp = e => {
    const { newDrawable, drawables } = this.state;
    if (newDrawable.length === 1) {
      const { x, y } = e.target.getStage().getPointerPosition();
      const drawableToAdd = newDrawable[0];
      drawableToAdd.registerMovement(x, y);
      drawables.push(drawableToAdd);
      this.setState({
        newDrawable: [],
        drawables
      });
    }
  };

  handleMouseMove = e => {
    const { newDrawable } = this.state;
    if (newDrawable.length === 1) {
      const { x, y } = e.target.getStage().getPointerPosition();
      const updatedNewDrawable = newDrawable[0];
      updatedNewDrawable.registerMovement(x, y);
      this.setState({
        newDrawable: [updatedNewDrawable]
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const drawables = [...this.state.drawables, ...this.state.newDrawable];
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={e => {
            this.setState({ newDrawableType: "ArrowDrawable" });
          }}
        >
          Draw Arrows
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={e => {
            this.setState({ newDrawableType: "CircleDrawable" });
          }}
        >
          Draw Circles
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={e => {
            this.setState({ newDrawableType: "FreePathDrawable" });
          }}
        >
          Draw FreeHand!
        </button>
        <Stage
          onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
          onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
          onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}
          width={900}
          height={700}
        >
          <Layer>
            {drawables.map(drawable => {
              return drawable.render();
            })}
          </Layer>
        </Stage>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return <SceneWithDrawables />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working example to play with:
https://codesandbox.io/s/w12qznzx5

Comment: thank you so much ! I didn't think about putting the arrow in an array and then just map it in the render. Will definitely help. Any idea on how to add multiple buttons, for example 'Pen' and 'Circle' so that the user can first choose, and then draw accordingly?

Comment: @HerbotSikaro I added a circle and a freehand drawing option (I guess that is what you ment by pen). It made it a bit more hairy, but managed to keep it under 200 lines and rather simple. Although in your own project, you should start thinking about breaking this thing up into separate files. If you have any more questions, ask away! I'll answer within 24h

Comment: @HerbotSikaro this week I have lots of work to do, but I'll try to have a look at it during the weekend, if you haven't found a solution in the meantime.

Comment: Sure, I have been trying but I can't figure it out, so I'm kinda waiting for your help.. :/ Those last 4 functionalities all present challenges that are very hard to grasp, and the few examples that I can find online are too simple to be applicable..

Comment: (Except the undo/redo that seems less complicated with a Stack type of data structure, I'm working on that now, I can't do the rest)

Comment: got any idea ?                     -

Comment: @pärt-johanson the example is really nice, do have an idea on how to draw a line or arrow but with two clicks? I mean click 1 start drawing, click two stops and finalizes the line.